# Android DatePicker always draw minimum 2 months and 2 days instead 1

Tags: android, datetimepicker

Try to draw only 1 day with 1 months 1 year with no scroll to other

**Layout:**

```
<DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/monthPickerFrom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:calendarViewShown="false"
                android:datePickerMode="spinner"
                />
```

**code:**

```
mDialogView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));       
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


        monthPickerTo = (DatePicker) mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.monthPickerTo);

        monthPickerTo.setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
        monthPickerTo.setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

but android 6 render this:
[custom dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzjwN.png)

i dont understant **where android taking day 02 and month June?!** but setMinDate and setMaxDate have equals DateTime. I tried 1000 times to remove not needed number and month - but i cant do this

and all OK with year: only 2017 drawing - this normal behaviour

**it is bug of Android?**

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you're trying to do. `1 day with 1 months 1 year` - is that the display format or date you're setting?

Comment: i want to see on view: 1 May 2017  (without 02 and Jun)

Comment: Make sure your device time is correct and is set to the correct time-zone

Comment: code have block: setMinDate = setMaxDate (last 2 lines). Hense, i have just 1 date. But why picker have next day and next month? http://imgur.com/4y0YPlE